# composer autoloading file does not work in laradock

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, laradock

I am trying to autoload a helpers.php file in my laravel application. This is my composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

My file path is correct and I have run dump-auotload command in workspace container serveral times:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now, when I try to call functions of that helper file in my blade files they're not recognized (undefined).

Comment: You can use composer update first of all and after  use this command you can run command composer dump autoload.

Comment: @vikas no effect